# setBackgroundResource acts different from setBackground with RippleDrawable

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I am trying to set a `RippleDrawable` as background to a list view row.
When using `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple)` everything works fine. 
When trying

```
view.setBackground(view.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple))
```

it works but the ripple doesn't show when quickly touching the item (I also have an activated/checked state for the item), it appears only when I keep the view pressed.

The setBackgroundResource method in View class looks like this :

```
if (resid != 0 && resid == mBackgroundResource) {
    return;
}

Drawable d = null;
if (resid != 0) {
    d = mContext.getDrawable(resid);
}
setBackground(d);

mBackgroundResource = resid;
```

so basically the exact thing I am trying to do manually.

NOTE: I want to use setBackground method because I want to create the RippleDrawable programatically.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the ripple on the row `View`, set it on the `ListView` using the `listSelector` attribute:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:listSelector="@drawable/ripple" />
```

Programmatically you can set it with `mListView.setSelector(...)`.

Comment: I need to have an `activated` state for the list row and the way I managed to achieve it was by using a background of the view directly and no `listSelector`. The ripple works fine using this approach it's only that I have to try to find a way to have the `activated` state correctly. It still seems odd to me why by using `setBackgroundResource` it works fine but with `setBackgroundDrawable` doesn't. Do you have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

call  **`View.invalidate();`** along with **`View.requestLayout();`**

the `CompoundButton` function `setChecked(boolean)` when used invalidates the `View` hence the `View` is asked to re-check itself and then re-drawn or layed out